# Joining two different columns from one table to the same column in a different table?

Tags: sql

I am working on a query that has fields called `ios_app_id`, `android_app_id` and `app_id`.
The `app_id` from **downloads** table can be either `ios_app_id` or `android_app_id` in the **products** table.

Is it correct that because of that I cannot just run a simple join of **downloads** and **products** table on on `p.ios_app_id = d.app_id` and then join again on on `p.android_app_id = d.app_id`? Would that cause an incorrect number of records?

```
select p.product_id, d.date, d.downloads,
from products p 
inner join download d
on p.ios_app_id = d.app_id

UNION 

select p.product_id, d.date, d.downloads
from products p
inner join download d
on p.android_app_id = d.app_id
```

I would try:

```
 select p.product_id, d.date, d.downloads,
    from products p 
    inner join downloads d
    on p.ios_app_id = d.app_id
    inner join downloads d
    on p.android_app_id = d.app_id
```

Basically I am trying to understand why the union here is needed instead of just joining the two fields twice? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `join` twice:

```
select p.product_id,
       coalesce(di.date, da.date),
       coalesce(di.downloads, da.downloads)
from products p left join
     downloads di
     on p.ios_app_id = di.app_id left join
     downloads da
     on p.android_app_id = da.app_id;
```

This should be more efficient than your method with `union`.  Basically, it attempts joining using the two ids.  The `coalesce()` combines the results into a single column.

Comment: Thanks I was confused as I was told union was the primary way to correctly join, what does the coalesce here serve for? I typically use it around a forumla and then 0 to account for nulls

Comment: when you use `left outer join` or `left join` there is a possibility that some query rows will NOT have any values coming from the left joined tables. i.e. NULLs. `coalesce()` is a SQL standard function that replaces NULLs  working left to right i.e. if the leftmost parameter is null it will look for a value in the next parameter and so on

Comment: Thanks @PaulMaxwell do you recommend using this coalesce method or union in this case?

Comment: "it depends" on what the full functional requirements are - they are not really specified. What is true is that you cannot get the correct numbers using inner joins as shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the purpose of an `INNER JOIN` is to get the values that exists on BOTH sets of data (lets called them table A and table B), using a specific column to join them. In your example, if you try to do the `INNER JOIN` twice, what would happen is that the first time you execute the `INNER JOIN`, the complete PRODUCTS table is your table A, and you obtain all the products that have downloaded the ios_app, but now (and this is the key part) this result becomes your new dataset, so it becomes your new table A for the next `inner join`. And thats the issue, cause what you would want is to join the whole table again, not just the result of the first join, but thats not how it works. This is why you need to use the `UNION`, cause you need to obtain your results independently and then add them.

An alternative would be to use `LEFT JOIN`, but you could get null values and duplicates -and its not too "clean"-. So, for your particular case, I think using `UNION` is much clearer and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you do left join in first query it will work.

```
create table all_products as (select p.product_id, d.date, d.downloads,
from products p 
left join downloads d
on p.ios_app_id = d.app_id)
```

```
select a.product_id, d.date, d.downloads from all_products a left join downloads d 
on a.android_app_id = d.app_id inner join
```